# Open folder view from asp.net website cross platforms and browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory, folderbrowserdialog

Working on a website solution and need to give user links for different folders on local computer. (Open explorer fileview)

I have worked two ways.

1) Simple link looking somting like this:

```
<a href="file:///H:/THEFOLDERTOOPEN/" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Works in IE but no other browsers.

2) Used: System.Diagnostics

```
Process.Start(@"file:///" + THEFOLDERTOOPEN);
```

This works across browsers working on local machine. But when using with http:// I am getting error:

```
Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
```

How to solve this issue??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

`Process.Start` Runs a process on your local computer (for example a program or opening a folder in windows explorer). It cannot be used with HTTP. What you are trying to achieve is actually not possible without using of Silverlight, Flash or any other Third Party Technology. You cannot simply access the file system from HTTP.

Comment: hi thanks for quick anwser. Can you help me in finding best case (and easyest) for making it work? Examples etc.?

Comment: @user2761009 as this is not my field of expertise and SO has a rule of one question per thread. I suggest you to open a new question. Thanks !

Comment: I had hoped for a uick fix :-) Thanks